# nginx configuration for multiple sites on same server

Tags: nginx

I am trying to create a nginx server that can host multiple sites on the same server. I have kept two different directories containing index.html files in the /var/www/ directory.

1st directory : dir1
Containing folder strucuture as : dir1/Folder/app;
app directory contains index.html for the site.

2nd directory : dir2
Containing folder strucuture as : dir2/Folder/app;
app directory contains index.html for the site.

now inside /etc/nginx/conf.d, created 2 .conf files as test.conf and dev.conf

test.conf :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.net;
    location /dir1/ {
        root /var/www/dir1/PharmacyAdminApp/app;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

dev.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.net;
    location /dir2/ {
        root /var/www/dir2/PharmacyAdminApp1/app;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

After this I restart the nginx server and visit "mydomain.net:80/dir1" on the browser but I get 404. Can anyone let me know what is the issue?

Comment: And if you try "mydomain.net:80/dir1/" in your browser? Same thing? (Notice the trailing slash in the URL)

Comment: Yes it happens the same for both dir1 and dir2.

Comment: Are you sure the config loaded? Try `nginx -t`. You have two identical server blocks (which is invalid). What you need is one server block containing the two location blocks.

Comment: Also, you need to use `alias` and not `root`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The above configuration should raise an error as you have defined two `default_server`, Also there is no point in defining two server blocks for the same domain,

This is how you can achieve it,

```
map $request_uri $rot {
    "~dir1" /var/www/dir1/Folder/app/;
    default /var/www/dir2/Folder/app/;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.net;
    root $rot;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/  index.html =404;
    }
}
```

The other way can be,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.net;

    location /dir2/ {
        root /var/www/dir2/PharmacyAdminApp1/app;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
    location /dir1/ {
        root /var/www/dir1/PharmacyAdminApp1/app;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

If it still throws any error, switch your error_log on, and check which files are being accessed, and correct from there.

Comment: If that solved your problem, can you please upvote as well? :)

Comment: Thanks Satys, it did solved my problem, but now I have different issue with this... When I am trying to visit the website on the browser, the following happens... The folder app contains different directories that have .js and .css files but the browser or nginx try to find them on server_name like http://server_name/components/order/orderCntrl.js whereas it should do as http://server_name/$root/components/order/orderCntrl.js  Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: can you tell, where are your js files kept for different /dir? and how do you access it, the url? are you currently getting 404?

Comment: js files are kept under app directory in different folder such as components. They are not getting loaded and I get a 404. The search should be server_name//var/www/dir1/PharmacyAdminApp1/app/components.

Comment: can you enter in your browser, domain.com/dir1/component/name.js and then in your error.log or access.log, do you see that the request is for /var/www/dir1/PharmacyAdminApp1/app/dir1/component/name.js? then add following lines into corresponding location block -> rewrite ^/dir1/(.*) /$1 break; before try_files.