# Nginx configuration for multi-project folders

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to set up nginx configuration file for multi-project php located in different folders. I have the following configuration file in my production server.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    error_log /LOGS/ardu_error.log debug;
    access_log /LOGS/ardu_access.log;

    set $applicationEnv "production";

    location ~ /ardu-component/ {
        root /srv/www/ardu-component/;

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        # the ubuntu default
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV $applicationEnv;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    #return 404 for all php files as we do have a front controller
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;

    error_log /LOGS/ardu_error.log debug;
    access_log /LOGS/ardu_access.log;

    set $applicationEnv "production";

    location ~ /ardu-component/ {
        root /srv/www/ardu-component/;

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        # the ubuntu default
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV $applicationEnv;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    #return 404 for all php files as we do have a front controller
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

I open my browser and I tried to connect to /ardu-component/ and I get `File not found` error from nginx.

In nginx debug log, I see the following information. It seems to start well resolving location and stuff, but it ends up in `/usr/share/nginx...` and I did not configure that in conf. I'm not devops, so I don't know how to solve this.

> 2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 http script var:
>   "/ardu-component/" 2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 trying to
>   use file: "/ardu-component/" "/srv/www/ardu-component/ardu-component/"
>   2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 http script copy:
>   "/index.php" 2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 http script
>   var: "" 2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 trying to use file:
>   "/index.php" "/srv/www/ardu-component/index.php" 2019/09/18 23:14:21
>   [debug] 2720#2720: *4 internal redirect: "/index.php?" 2019/09/18
>   23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 rewrite phase: 1
>   ...
>   2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 http script var:
>   "/usr/share/nginx/html" 2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 http
>   script var: "/index.php" 2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4
>   fastcgi param: "SCRIPT_FILENAME: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php"
>   2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 http script copy: "HTTPS"
>   2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 http script copy: "off"
>   2019/09/18 23:14:21 [debug] 2720#2720: *4 fastcgi param: "HTTPS: off"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx configuration for multiple sites on same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244150/nginx-configuration-for-multiple-sites-on-same-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first if server_name , your localhost , set localhost

second set your /srv/www

code

```
server {  
     location ~ /\. { deny  all; }
    listen *:80 ;       
     server_name   localhost     ;
      root   /srv/www;


    location / {root   /srv/www/;




                    index  index.htm  index.html  index.php;
    }



   location ^~ /ardu-component {    
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }


        location ~ ^/.+\.php {
              fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/lecad/public_html/$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=\"/srv/www/:/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php:\"
    include_path=\"/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp:/srv/www/\"";
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }}
```

**if that not work  , try**

update

```
try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
```

to

```
try_files /ardu-component/$uri /ardu-component/index.php$is_args$args;
```

hoping that help you